# Write data into new row in excel file whenever i run the code using Apache POI in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

i am new to selenium and java , i am trying to write data into new row in excel file whenever i run the code using Apache POI in Selenium WebDriver. I have the following code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.google.common.collect.Table.Cell;

public class ExcelWrite {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException 
    {

        File file = new File("D:\\Selenium_Training\\SeleniumFile.xlsx");

        FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream(file);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int x = sh.getLastRowNum();

        if(x==0)
        {
            XSSFRow row = sh.createRow(0);

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("TC001");
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Successfully logged in");
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");

        }
        else
        {
            int y=x++;

            XSSFRow row1 = sh.createRow(y);
            row1.createCell(0).setCellValue("TC001");
            row1.createCell(1).setCellValue("Successfully logged in");
            row1.createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");            

        }

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

        wb.write(fout);

        fout.close();

    }

}
```

I am getting the following error when i run the code,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (no sheets)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(XSSFWorkbook.java:1061)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(XSSFWorkbook.java:848)
    at day1.ExcelWrite.main(ExcelWrite.java:28)
```

From the helps given , i have modified the code as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException 
    {

        File file = new File("D:\\Selenium_Training\\SeleniumFile.xlsx");

        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);

        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int x = sh.getLastRowNum();

        if(x==0)
        {
            XSSFRow row = sh.createRow(0);

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue("TC001");
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Successfully logged in");
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");

        }
        else
        {
            int y=x++;

            XSSFRow row1 = sh.createRow(y);
            row1.createCell(0).setCellValue("TC001");
            row1.createCell(1).setCellValue("Successfully logged in");
            row1.createCell(2).setCellValue("Pass");            

        }

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);

        wb.write(fout);

        fout.close();

    }
```

But now i am getting the below error ,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.io.IOException: Can't obtain the input stream from /docProps/app.xml
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:141)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:177)
    at day1.ExcelWrite.main(ExcelWrite.java:57)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't obtain the input stream from /docProps/app.xml
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getInputStream(PackagePart.java:500)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLProperties.<init>(POIXMLProperties.java:75)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:139)
    ... 2 more
```

Could you please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check how many sheets are there in your `Excel`?

Comment: I checked the excel file and by default it has three sheets i.e., sheet1,sheet2 and sheet3.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with these three lines:

```
    File file = new File("D:\\Selenium_Training\\SeleniumFile.xlsx");
    FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Here you are making two mistakes. Firstly, you're ignoring your file, and creating a new empty workbook. Secondly, you're trying to [use an InputStream when you have a File, which the docs explain is slower and uses more memory](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

You'd be best off just replacing that code with either:

```
    File file = new File("D:\\Selenium_Training\\SeleniumFile.xlsx");
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

Or:

```
    File file = new File("D:\\Selenium_Training\\SeleniumFile.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.open(file);
```

Plus using the common SS classes like `Sheet` and `Row` in place of the XSSF-specific ones like `XSSFSheet` as you do now - that would let your code work for both `.xlsx` and `.xls` files

Comment: thanks for your valuable help ,but now i am getting different error , could you please help me , i have given the modified code above.
Thanks in advance.